# Flutter google map showing no map

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I am working on an app that requires google map functionality. I have generated a key and in flutter I am using the following package

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_maps#-readme-tab-

The issue is my map doesnt seem to be working. I just see a blank white page

my manifest.xml

```xml
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="wmbsender"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_KEY"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

........
```

```dart
class Receiver extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<GoogleMapStateBase> _key = GlobalKey<GoogleMapStateBase>();
  final Set<Marker> markers = new Set();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    markers.add(Marker(GeoCoord(30,77)));

    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: GoogleMap(
          key: _key,
          initialPosition: GeoCoord(30.1290, 77.2674),
          mapType: MapType.roadmap,
          markers: markers,
          mobilePreferences: MobileMapPreferences(
              myLocationEnabled: true, myLocationButtonEnabled: true),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get this crazy big log too

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
D/EGL_emulation( 5862): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf2a24890: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf2d7ae90)
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:38467/9zTpl7DCgWc=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 arm...
I/zzbz    ( 5862): Making Creator dynamically
W/Gralloc4( 5862): allocator 3.x is not supported
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Unsupported class loader
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Unsupported class loader
I/DynamiteModule( 5862): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:222
I/DynamiteModule( 5862): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 222
V/DynamiteModule( 5862): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/Context;->getFeatureId()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/Context;->createFeatureContext(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Context; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Unsupported class loader
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Unsupported class loader
I/Google Maps Android API( 5862): Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API( 5862): Google Play services package version: 201214022
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  ( 5862): uid=10151(com.example.wmbsender) identical 3 lines
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  ( 5862): uid=10151(com.example.wmbsender) identical 4 lines
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekLong(JZ)J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeLong(JJZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeInt(JIZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekInt(JZ)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByte(JB)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByte(J)B (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayBaseOffset(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayIndexScale(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/TetheringManager( 5862): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.wmbsender
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
D/HostConnection( 5862): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf2c1fd50, tid 5971
D/EGL_emulation( 5862): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf2a1c320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf2d79e30)
D/HostConnection( 5862): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/EGL_emulation( 5862): eglCreateContext: 0xf2a0e2b0: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
D/EGL_emulation( 5862): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf2a0e2b0: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xbfe9a550)
E/Google Maps Android API( 5862): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API( 5862): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
E/Google Maps Android API( 5862): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
E/Google Maps Android API( 5862): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
E/Google Maps Android API( 5862):   API Key: AIzaSyD_STiFnvY5N2n53oEu-34SNUFiNE0Z85g
E/Google Maps Android API( 5862):   Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 66:8C:33:5F:8A:FA:53:DF:81:3E:F7:5E:DB:A7:CB:8F:7A:AB:69:D7;com.example.wmbsender
W/DynamiteModule( 5862): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 5862): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
I/DynamiteModule( 5862): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Unsupported class loader
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Unsupported class loader
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  ( 5862): uid=10151(com.example.wmbsender) androidmapsapi- identical 4 lines
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  ( 5862): uid=10151(com.example.wmbsender) Jit thread pool identical 1 line
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ample.wmbsende( 5862): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
```

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you don't have `Google Maps Android API v2` activate in your Google Cloud Console.

Try to set  `Maps SDK for Android` up enable.

Comment: yeah I figured that out. Really this is very cumbersome work by google.

Comment: Super terrible documentation on this issue! I wasted like 2 hours on this.  Thanks